# Est-il correct d'écrire "Il vient de monter en voiture" au sens de "Il vient de monter dans sa voiture" pour donner un aspect de légèreté à la phrase?

Tags: syntaxe, constructions, formulation

Il s'agit bel et bien de la voiture de la personne qui s'exprime. C'est un syntagme qui apparaît dans le dictionnaire "CNRTL".

Merci.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oui, c'est possible, mais alors si l'auditeur ou le lecteur ne sait pas à qui appartient la voiture, rien ne lui indique cela et la personne qui monte en voiture peut très bien être montée dans la voiture de quelqu'un d'autre.
Par exemple, on prend le contexte de plusieurs voitures et personnes dans une cour, la voiture de la personne de laquelle on parle y étant garée ; cette personne n'a pas à utiliser sa propre voiture et peut très bien partir avec un autre conducteur.

Answer (score 0):

La phrase *monter en voiture* signifie **prendre une voiture et s'en aller** (partir) alors que *monter dans la voiture* signifie seulement **rentrer à l'intérieur de la voiture** (s'installer).

Dans la phrase, *en voiture* est employé comme un adverbe (c.f. adverbial) bien que *en* soit en fait une préposition.